# Can't install gevent on termux, anyone can help me?

Tags: gevent, termux

~ $ pip install gevent
Collecting gevent
Using cached gevent-21.12.0.tar.gz (6.2 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done                  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done

Collecting zope.event
Using cached zope.event-4.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from gevent) (58.1.0)

Collecting zope.interface
Using cached zope.interface-5.4.0-cp310-cp310-linux_aarch64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet<2.0,>=1.1.0 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from gevent) (1.1.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: gevent

Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [63 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.10/gevent.libuv._corecffi.c'
Running '(cd

"/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-55j041qz/gevent_018671f4e2174ad19170736008c5782a/deps/libev"  && sh ./configure -C

> configure-output.txt )' in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-55j041qz/gevent_018671f4e2174ad19170736008c5782a
> configure: error: no acceptable ld found in $PATH
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in 
> main()
> File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
> json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])

```
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 230, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 481, in <module>
      run_setup(EXT_MODULES)
    File "setup.py", line 348, in run_setup
      setup(
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 155, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()






    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 143, in run
      ext.sources[0] = make_mod(self.build_temp, pre_run)
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-l1wl_veu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 128, in make_mod
      pre_run(ext, ffi)
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-55j041qz/gevent_018671f4e2174ad19170736008c5782a/_setuputils.py", line 364, in pre_run
      action()
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-55j041qz/gevent_018671f4e2174ad19170736008c5782a/_setuplibev.py", line 55, in configure_libev
      system(libev_configure_command)
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-55j041qz/gevent_018671f4e2174ad19170736008c5782a/_setuputils.py", line 195, in system
      if _system(cmd, cwd=cwd, env=env, **kwargs):
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-55j041qz/gevent_018671f4e2174ad19170736008c5782a/_setuputils.py", line 191, in _system
      return check_call(cmd, cwd=cwd, env=env, **kwargs)
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '(cd  "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-55j041qz/gevent_018671f4e2174ad19170736008c5782a/deps/libev"  && sh ./configure -C > configure-output.txt )' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for gevent
Failed to build gevent
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gevent, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
~ $

Comment: try ```apt update;apt full-upgrade;apt install gevent;```

Answer (score 0):

try lower versions
https://pypi.org/project/gevent/#history
I have tried all the versions I see 20.4.0 Is the best

Answer (score 0):

Try:

pkg install binutils

This worked for me.